# Is my Rolling Walk Forward Code Correct (Python)?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to code a rolling walk forward function on my own as shown below with a bit of modification. I'm basically trying to test trading strategies with it. Below is my code and was wondering if it works as intended for this.

[Rolling Walk Forward Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyF8W.png)

```
data_shape      = (1000,1)
validation_bars = 100
warm_up_bars    = 50
training_bars   = 200
endpoint        = data_shape[0]-validation_bars-warm_up_bars


print(f"Endpoint is at {endpoint} ")

for i in range(warm_up_bars, endpoint, validation_bars):
    print("Index is "+str(i))
    train_start_idx       = i
    train_end_idx         = train_start_idx + training_bars
    validation_start_idx  = train_end_idx
    validation_end_idx    = validation_start_idx +validation_bars
    print(f"Training Set Index is from {train_start_idx} to {train_end_idx}")
    print(f"Validation Set Index is from {validation_start_idx} to {validation_end_idx}")
    print("\n")
```

So basically I have a sample dataset shape of 1,000 rows and 1 column. The warm up bars is basically the first 50 in this example to get the strategy set with initial parameters. And then break apart the set of data into training and validation sets. Each iteration moves ahead by how big the `validation set` is. Is my code right for a Rolling Walk Forward Test? Thanks

I went ahead and tested it on different data sizes and it seems to work but I am not sure since I am new to this. Just want to make sure that my code works as intended. Thanks

Comment: the code works fine.  Were you expecting something different ?

Comment: @D.L Just wondering if it's  implemented properly for a walk forward analysis?